# Echarts roam function

Tags: echarts

The roam function of echarts only work when we're at in the chart itself which seems make sense

But what I'm tryin to do is to Make roam works at the parent which is a card
for example I'm zooming in the corner of the card; it should work
but now it only works at the chart (doesn't matter which chart is it )

Can someone tell me how to make roaming in all parent component?